# in_array fails when using implode in if statement

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, implode

This attamept is to create a search condition where eventually the output will be processed to show results based on increasing order of matches

"PHP implode function in if and foreach condition [closed]" is a different question !

Why is the following code failing ?

```
$terms = array("HELLO", "HI", "HOWDY");
$row = array("HELLO", "HI", "Hey");
$chkcond = "in_array('".implode("',$"."row".")"." && in_array"."('",$terms)."',$"."row)";

echo "$chkcond<br/><br/>";

if ($chkcond) {
    echo "All Found in Array !<br>";}else{echo "Not Found !<br/>";
}
```

The echo result is

```
in_array('HELLO',$row) && in_array('HI',$row) && in_array('HOWDY',$row)
```

And the if condition outputs `"All Found in Array !"`

When the `if` condition says that all three terms have to be in the row array to be "`All Found in Array`", then why is it returning `True` when "`Howdy`" doesn't exist in the row array ?

Comment: Because you are doing this all wrong, why are you wrapping actual php function calls in quotes?

Comment: I'm not even sure what the hell you try to do in your code. Looks like you need to go back to the basics.

Comment: `$chkcond` is a string. You could use `eval` but this is strange usage..

Comment: What did you smoke?

Comment: I am trying to create a search function. Where there could hundreds of needles to be found from a huge haystack ! So I thought implode and array would make it shorter and faster. I have a smilar working sql query with implode on my site.

Comment: I have seen there are million duplicates here on stack overflow...when i typed the question the one mentioned by @Sumitpatel ddn't turn up ! How was I supposed to know ?! And that too that question is totally different !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

juste use `array_diff` http://php.net/array_diff

```
<?php
$terms=array("HELLO","HI","HOWDY");
$row=array("HELLO","HI","Hey");

$diff = array_diff($terms, $row);

if (0 === count($diff)){echo "All terms Found in Array row !<br>";}else{echo "Not all terms Found in Array row !<br>";}


$terms=array("HELLO","HI","HOWDY");
$row=array("HELLO","HI","Hey","HOWDY");

$diff = array_diff($terms, $row);

if (0 === count($diff)){echo "All terms Found in Array row !<br>";}else{echo "Not all terms Found in Array row !<br>";}
```

Comment: Yep. I think this would be better that trying out a new stunt ! Thanks @mmm  :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)

Something like:

```
<?php
$terms=array("HELLO","HI","HOWDY");
$row=array("HELLO","HI","Hey");
$chkcond=array_diff($terms, $row);

var_dump($chkcond);

if(empty($chkcond)) {
    echo "All Found in Array !<br>";
} else {
    echo "Not Found !<br>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are attempting but you can use array_diff.

```
$terms = array("HELLO","HI","HOWDY");
$row   = array("HELLO","HI","Hey");

$differences = array_diff($terms, $row);

if ($differences) {
  echo "All Found in array";
} else {
  "Not Found !<br>";
}
```

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to stick with `in_array` you need to loop your terms:

```
<?php
    $terms=array("HELLO","HI","HOWDY");
    $row=array("HELLO","HI","Hey");

    $chkcond = true;
    foreach($row as $needle){
        if(!in_array($needle, $terms)){
            $chkcond = false;
            break;         
        }
    }

    if($chkcond){
        echo "All Found in Array !<br>";
    } else {
        echo "Not Found !<br>";
    }
?>
```

Heck re-reading the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php you do not even need to loop:

```
<?php
    $terms=array("HELLO","HI","HOWDY");
    $row=array("HELLO","HI","Hey");
    if(in_array($row, $terms)){
        echo "All Found in Array !<br>";
    } else {
        echo "Not Found !<br>";
    }

?>
```